# A basic question about raw pdf file output by pdftex

Tags: pdftex, pdf

Consider the following simple `tex` file, to be compiled with `pdflatex`.

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\documentclass{standalone}
\begin{document}
\hrulefill
\end{document}
```

Thanks to `\pdfcompresslevel=0`, the resulting `pdf` file is human readable. One can find the following lines:

```
4 0 obj <<
/Type /ObjStm
/N 4
/First 22
/Length 257       
>>
stream
2 0 1 105 5 139 6 191
% 2 0 obj
<<
/Type /Page
/Contents 3 0 R
/Resources 1 0 R
/MediaBox [0 0 343.711 0.398]
/Parent 5 0 R
>>
% 1 0 obj
<<
/ProcSet [ /PDF ]
>>
% 5 0 obj
<<
/Type /Pages
/Count 1
/Kids [2 0 R]
>>
% 6 0 obj
<<
/Type /Catalog
/Pages 5 0 R
>>
endstream
endobj
```

As far as I understand, a call like `5 0 R` refers to the object defined by `5 0 obj`. Such an object seems indeed to be defined but with a leading `%` that is supposed to be the comment char in pdf format.

So two questions.

1. Is my analysis right?
2. Why does `pdftex` output such comments (I mean why does it output `% 2 0 obj`)?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

What you see is not the completely un-compressed PDF. To get such, you will have to say

```
\pdfcompresslevel=0
\pdfobjcompresslevel=0
```

There are two different levels of compression according to the PDF specification.

The first one, controlled by the value of `\pdfcompresslevel` in the `pdftex` driver, deals with the content streams of page objects, XObjects, embedded files and others, that is, data enclosed between `stream` and `endstream` keywords.

Secondly, PDF objects of a PDF file can themselves be packed into content streams of container objects of type `/ObjStm`. This is controlled by `\pdfobjcompresslevel`.

Since, in the example code, `\pdfcompresslevel` is set to zero, the content stream of the `/ObjStm` object No. 4, as listed in the second code box, is not compressed. One can see the objects that are packed into it. The first line, immediately after the `stream` keyword, lists the number and byte offset within the stream for all packed objects. The commented object numbers are only there for information.

Comment: Thank you so much: it's clearer now. This was turning me absolutely mad.